# RESTful API and stats page

Tags: rest, design-patterns

I have a RESTful API that manages customers and payments.

I've been requested to create a stats page with data like:

- total number of customers
- how many customers are active/inactive
- total number of payments
- how many payments failed/were successful
- how many payments failed/were successful per day
- how many payments failed/were successful per month
- how much money was earned per day
- how much money was earned per month
- and other more

I have endpoints for everything and I can retrieve customers calling `api/customers` and payments by calling `api/payments`. I know I could call `api/payments?status=successful` and `api/payments?status=failed` to get the data that I need, however the system has hundreds of payments and thousands of customers and each query takes its time to process. Also, I know I could retrieve all payment stats with a single query with a `group by` statement.

My question is: would it break RESTful conventions to create a new endpoint for each required stat? This would allow me to create "optimized" queries for each metric.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> would it break RESTful conventions to create a new endpoint for each required stat?

No.

Remember, the reference application for the [REST architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is the world wide web.  Adding a new web page is a perfectly normal thing to do.  So to it is with [resources](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1).

Answer (score 1):

RESTful is just an architectural style for your APIs. If you read the RFC you will find out that none of the RESTful APIs are truly RESTful. There is a huge amount of suggestions in order to actually implement such an API.

My opinion (and answer) on your question is that such an architecture is more like a guideline to structure your API other than following it strictly. Software engineering is all about taking such decisions, there is no perfect answer, you just pick trade-offs.